# Create Summary of tabs with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a summary page that will report ONLY tabs that contain conditional formatting that's true. So Tab1 contains a comparison of Before and After; the After will highlight any cells that are different than the Before; then the macro loops to do this with a new tab for every .jbi file in a folder. So each .jbi will have a copy of Tab1 named differently. I'm not sure which method would be better to identify tabs with highlighted changes on a summary page nor really how to go about searching each tab for them.

So my questions are - Should I 1.) make it part of the .jbi import loop where it creates a new copy of Tab1, pastes the before and after data, then resets the template 2.) have it look for changes once it has completed creating new tabs?
3.) How do I get it to search for true conditional formats either way?

Edit: Using the suggestion in the first comment, this is what I came up with, but it doesn't work. It never copies the values

```
Sub Create_summary()
Dim inputarea As Range
Set inputarea = Sheets("PGM Copy Template").Range("AF2:BA1000")


If inputarea.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 49407 Then
    Sheets("Change Summary").Select
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        If Sheets("PGM Copy Template").Range("F4").Value = "#N/A" Then
        Sheets("Change Summary").Range("B3").Text = Sheets("PGM Copy Template").Range("AI5").Text
        Sheets("Change Summary").Range("C3").Text = Sheets("PGM Copy Template").Range("AI4").Text
        Else
        Sheets("Change Summary").Range("B3").Text = Sheets("PGM Copy Template").Range("F5").Text
        Sheets("Change Summary").Range("B3").Text = Sheets("PGM Copy Template").Range("F4").Text
        End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

I guess I need help understanding how I can make the If/then function with the search.

Comment: If there's only one known color for `True` then you can check the cells in the range for `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = myCFTrueColor`

Comment: Cool, I'll see if I can get that to do what I need. Just really need it to satisfy an if statement so I can copy a couple of things.

Comment: I updated the post with the code I created, and I just can't get it to work with the if/then to copy the pgm# and Comment from the copy template over to the list on Change Summary

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that the entirety of the inputrange won't be colored yellow, just whichever cells are different than the Before side?

Comment: You can't test the color of a multi-cell range like that.  You need to use a loop like `Dim c As Range: For Each c in inputarea.Cells` and check each cell which might contain CF.  Is there some relationship between what you need to copy and the cell(s) where the format condition is True though?  Your posted code only has fixed sources, so do you only need to know if *any one* cell meets the condition?

Comment: If ANY cell within the range shown is true, I need to copy information elsewhere on the sheet to the Summary page. So it's creating kind of a table of contents for where changes exist, but I don't actually care what the changes are or to list them specifically, just on which tabs they occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit easier to split out the check for the CF color:

```vb
Sub Create_summary()
    Const CHECK_COLOR As Long = 49407 'use Const for fixed values
    Dim inputarea As Range, wb As Workbook, wsInput As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet, isNA As Boolean
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook    'ActiveWorkbook?        'use a workbook variable
    Set wsInput = wb.Worksheets("PGM Copy Template") 'use worksheet variables
    Set wsSummary = wb.Worksheets("Change Summary")
    
    If HasCfColor(wsInput.Range("AF2:BA1000"), CHECK_COLOR) Then
        isNA = wsInput.Range("F4").Value = "#N/A"
        With Sheets("Change Summary")
            .Rows(3).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            .Range("B3").Text = wsInput.Range(IIf(isNA, "AI5", "F5")).Text
            .Range("C3").Text = wsInput.Range(IIf(isNA, "AI4", "F4")).Text
        End With
    End If

End Sub

'Does range `rngToCheck` contain a cell with CF coloring of `cfColor` ?
Function HasCfColor(rngToCheck As Range, cfColor As Long)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no CF in this range
    Set rng = rngToCheck.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions) 'only cells with CF
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'True if have any  cells with CF
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = cfColor Then
                HasCfColor = True
                Exit Function 'done checking
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    HasCfColor = False
End Function
```

Comment: This worked great! I understand where I was having issues before, there was just a lot more to it than I expected. Really appreciate the help!